# How to send Basic HTML Form data to Spring Boot controller?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

How to send HTML Form request i.e; value of 'input' to @PostMapping in controller without creating any POJO class or jsp?

```
<body>
    <form method="post" id="form">
        <input type ="text"/>
    </form>
    
    <button type="button" id="button2" >Submit2</button>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Script2.js

```
var select = document.getElementById('form');

document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(){
    var value = select.value
    window.location.href = "/posting";
};
```

MyController.java

```
@PostMapping(value="/posting")
    public String po() {
        return "hello";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **@RequestParam** see [RequestParam in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)

add action attribute to form and  make button in form **(not needed js file because send direct by form)**:

```
<body>
  <form action="/posting" method="post" id="form">
    <input type ="text" name="someName"/>
    <button type="submit" id="button2" >Submit2</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

and change in controller :

```
@PostMapping("/posting")
public String po(@RequestParam("someName") String someName) {
   return "hello" + someName;
}
```

but if need use js file you can use **XMLHttpRequest** see [XMLHttpRequest api](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) or **ajax** see [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or **fetch** [fetch api](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/api_fetch.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the name for your input element:

```
<body>
  <form method="post" id="form">
    <input type ="text" name="someName"/>
  </form>

  <button type="button" id="button2" >Submit2</button>
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

In your script create HTTPRequest and send data:

```
var select = document.getElementById('form');
    
document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(){
  var data = new FormData(select);

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", "/posting");
  req.send(data);
};
```

You may also want to send JSON data. Convert data to JSON and send json variable

```
var object = {};
data.forEach(function(value, key){
   object[key] = value;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
req.send(json);
```

And in java controller you have to specify that the method parameter is a request body. Something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/posting")
public String po(@RequestBody String someName) {
    return "hello" + someName;
}
```

Check if controller class has @RequestMapping("/") annotation

Comment: Hi @Art Zhiltsoff! Still I am unable to hit @PostMapping(value="/posting") in my spring boot application. Please tell me how to extract sent data out of @PostMapping(value="/posting") also.

Comment: Added code to my answer

Comment: Getting this error -> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing, So i changed( var data = new FormData(select)) to ( var data = new FormData(select.name)), error is gone but still unable to hit PostMapping

Comment: What annotation do you have for controller class?

Comment: @ResTController

Comment: Seems you miss `@RequestMapping`. Both should be there: 
`@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
or
@RequestMapping("/posting")
`