# Handling of aUndefined list of issues in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, forms, thymeleaf

I have a webpage with an undefined list of things with checkboxes.
[image: website]

On the controller side, I want to get an array of strings that have been selected.

What is the best way to do this with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf?

Regards,

Robert

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you may be getting stuck? What does your code look like (as a [mre])? What happens? What errors do you get? What about guidance in questions such as [How to send Basic HTML Form data to Spring Boot controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73513133/12567365) - and other [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+post+form+data+site:stackoverflow.com)? Do any of those help?

Comment: There are also various [checkbox-related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+form+submit+checkboxes+site:stackoverflow.com). Without more info we can only guess at the best ways to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints. I don't have code yet and errors. I only have one spring boot with thymeleaf application and am looking for the best way to solve my problem